# How Can I Solve Visual Studio Code Error?

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, performance, dart

I'm trying to run my first app in visual studio
But I اhave an error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\jars-9\f596b4dd337df4b4bc8d9a578e73e7d7\gradle-7.1.2.jar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYpIs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

1. delete the PUBSPEC.YAML file

After this:

2. Write a command on the terminal

> flutter pub get

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Actually this didn't help me I got another error PS C:\devolpment\fApp\Fapp\flutter_application_1> flutter pub get
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.